# Python combinations of 2 lists

Tags: python, optimization, performance

What is the `pythonic` way to calculated all the product combinations of two lists. So given two lists of length `n` I'd liked to return a list of length `2^n` containing the products.

Like `list(itertools.product(on,off))` but the results should use all four elements not only combination pairs like:

```
[(1.05, 5.53), (1.05, 3.12), (1.05, 3.75), (1.05, 4.75), (1.5, 5.53), (1.5, 3.12), (1.5, 3.75), (1.5, 4.75), (2.1, 5.53), (2.1, 3.12), (2.1, 3.75), (2.1, 4.75), (1.7, 5.53), (1.7, 3.12), (1.7, 3.75), (1.7, 4.75)]
```

So more like this:

```
off = [5.53,3.12,3.75,4.75]
on = [1.05,1.5,2.1,1.7]

# calculate combinations
x = combinations(on,off)

# Where... 
# x[0] = off[0] * off[1] * off[2] * off[3] i.e
# x[0] = 5.53 * 3.12 * 3.75 * 4.75
#
# x[1] = off[0] * off[1] * off[2] * on[3] i.e
# x[1] = 5.53 * 3.12 * 3.75 * 1.7
#
# x[2] = off[0] * off[1] * on[2] * on[3] i.e
# x[2] = 5.53 * 3.12 * 2.1 * 1.7
#
# ...
#
# x[15] = on[0] * on[1] * on[2] * on[3] i.e
# x[15] = 1.05 * 1.5 * 2.1 * 1.7
```

The output can be similar to the `itertools.product()` method *i.e* `[(5.53, 3.12, 3.75, 4.75),(5.53, 3.12, 3.75, 1.7), ...]`  I need to calculate the product but I'm interesting in the combination method.

*Note:* When I say `pythonic` way of doing this I mean a simple one or two lines taking advantage of pythons structures, libraries *(itertools ect)*.

Comment: you want the cartesian product of the lists?

Comment: @Woot4Moo No, that is what `itertools.product()` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate all `2**4` possibilities by starting with `itertools.product([0, 1], 4)`.  This enumerates all possible sequences of `0`s and `1`s of length 4, and then you can translate each 0-1 sequence to a sequence of values from `off` and `on`, by taking `off[i]` if the ith element of the 0-1 sequence is `0`, and `on[i]` otherwise.  In code:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> off = [5.53,3.12,3.75,4.75]
>>> on = [1.05,1.5,2.1,1.7]
>>> for choices in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=len(off)):
...     print [(on[i] if choice else off[i]) for i, choice in enumerate(choices)]
... 
[5.53, 3.12, 3.75, 4.75]
[5.53, 3.12, 3.75, 1.7]
[5.53, 3.12, 2.1, 4.75]
[5.53, 3.12, 2.1, 1.7]
... <10 more entries omitted ...>
[1.05, 1.5, 2.1, 4.75]
[1.05, 1.5, 2.1, 1.7]
```

To print the products instead of the lists:

```
>>> import operator
>>> for choices in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=len(off)):
...     elts = [(on[i] if choice else off[i]) for i, choice in enumerate(choices)]
...     print reduce(operator.mul, elts, 1)
... 
307.32975
109.9917
172.10466
61.595352
...
```

If you have numpy available and are willing to work with numpy arrays instead of Python lists, then there are some nice tools like [numpy.choose](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html) available.  For example:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.choose([0, 1, 0, 1], [off, on])
array([ 5.53,  1.5 ,  3.75,  1.7 ])
>>> numpy.product(numpy.choose([0, 1, 0, 1], [off, on]))
52.880624999999995
```

Combining with the earlier solutions gives:

```
>>> for c in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=4):
...     print numpy.product(numpy.choose(c, [off, on]))
... 
307.32975
109.9917
172.10466
61.595352
147.7546875
52.880625
...
```

Answer (score 5):

You were very close, [`itertools.combinations()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

Comment: I don't think my question was clear enough `list(itertools.combinations(off+on,4))` produces the number of ways to order 8 items in length of groups of 4.. i.e n!/(k!(n-k)!) = 70 ways. I want the 16 Binary combinations, think of it as a sports bet 8 teams are playing, the number of results for the 4 matches is 16 different combinations. Hope this clears up what I am asking for.

Comment: @sudo_o -- This still seems unclear.  If it's 8 teams playing, how are the teams matched up?  `off[i]` plays `on[i]`?  If thats the case, why do you expect to get `x[1] = off[0] * off[1] * off[2] * on[0]` instead of `x[1] = off[0] * off[1] * off[2] * on[3]`?

Comment: @mgilson Yes `off[i]` vs `on[i]` it was a typo thanks for pointing it out, I have made the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

```
off = [5.53,3.12,3.75,4.75]
on = [1.05,1.5,2.1,1.7]
import itertools as it
import operator

indices = list(it.product([0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]))
off_on = off,on
a = [reduce(operator.mul,(off_on[z][i] for i,z in enumerate(x))) for x in indices]
print a


#Numpy solution
import numpy as np
indices = list(it.product([0,1],[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]))
off_on = off,on
b = np.array([off,on])
loff = range(len(off))
aa = [np.prod(b[list(x),loff]) for x in indices]

print aa
print aa == a
```

Comment: Please see my comment on Lattyware's answers and Mark Dickinson answer. I don't think I was clear enough but I'm not trying to calculate `n!/(k!(n-k)!`

Comment: `print len(a)` gives 70 not 16 so nope.